# Manually set color for venn diagrams in Vennerable package

Tags: r, venn-diagram

Hi I would like to be able to manually assign the colors. 
For example

```
library(Vennerable)
data(StemCell)
  w <- Venn(Sets=StemCell[1:2])
  plot(w, type="squares")
```

produces 
[image]

however what I would like to do is manaully change the color, OCT4=red, overlap=brown and Sox2=green? 
is this possible with the current package?  I tried setting gpar but it did not appear to do anything in particular.

thanks!
A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of this is documented in the Vennerable vignette (vignette("Venn")), section 2.3 Graphical parameters, and the VennThemes man page (?VennThemes)

The customization that you would like to have requires you to make use of compute.Venn() additional to Venn(), to compute an appropriate diagram that you can then customize using VennThemes().

The code for your required customization looks like this:

```
w <- compute.Venn(Venn(Sets=StemCell[1:2]), type = "squares")
gp <- VennThemes(w)
gp[["Face"]][["11"]]$fill <-  "brown"
gp[["Face"]][["01"]]$fill <-  "green"
gp[["Face"]][["10"]]$fill <-  "red"
plot(w, gp = gp)
```

[image: Customized Venn plot]

You can look at the object "gp", that contains all visualization settings, like fill of the Venn that is altered in the code above, but also colour of line, text, etc. Have fun playing around with that.

btw, in the vignette, they make use of grid package

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
```

to wipe the slate. Otherwise you're plotting Venn on top of Venn diagram.

Comment: this great. it works! Do you know if its possible to reuse the theme once its created. The only thing I can think of perhaps is to wrap that up as a function and just reuse it.  Anyway, cool thanks.

Comment: Not sure about that. Since gp depends on the venn object created by compute.Venn(Venn((...), I'd guess that you can't just reapply gp on any given venn object unless it's very similar (perhaps slightly different numbers, but otherwise the same), and even then I'm not sure. gp for instance contains how many circles and overlaps the object consists of. Just check the content of gp to see what it contains, and simply try it.

Comment: thanks again.  I end up wrapping this into a simple function so that all I had to do was provide two vectors.